# Templated Virtual Function Alternatives

Tags: c++, oop, types, c++17

What are the alternatives to templated virtual functions?

Here is an abstraction of my setup case:

```
class CParent
{
    bool m_bExampleParentData = true;

public:
    template< typename t > virtual operator t( ) = 0;
};

class CChild1: public CParent
{
    char m_chExampleChild1Data = 'c';

public:
    operator char & ( ) override
    {
        return m_chExampleChild1Data;
    }
};

class CChild2: public CParent
{
    int m_iExampleChild2Data = 17;

public:
    operator int & ( ) override
    {
        return m_iExampleChild2Data;
    }
};
```

Here is an abstraction of my use case:

```
int main( )
{
    std::vector< CParent * > vecAbstractPointers;

    CChild1 child1;
    vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( reinterpret_cast< CParent * >( &child1 ) );
    CChild2 child2;
    vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( reinterpret_cast< CParent * >( &child2 ) );

    *vecAbstractPointers[ 0 ] /*char( child1 )*/ = 'b';
    *vecAbstractPointers[ 1 ] /*int( child2 )*/ = 8;
}
```

I'm sure there is something stupidly obvious and much simpler than this code, but I can't think of it for the life of me.

This will hopefully achieve the ability to assign members of the children classes through a virtual function in the parent class without knowing the types of the members of the children class. I figure if there isn't anything I can do myself, I may be able to implement something using the standard (like `std::variant` or `std::any`) but I'd like to avoid that. I'm trying to keep the end code as absent of casting as possible (thus the implicit casting).

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Let's accept for the sake of argument that you managed to define your classes the way you want. How would a user of your library, having only a bunch of `CParent*` pointers in hand, know to assign a `char` to some and an `int` to others? The whole point of a polymorphic base class is that it presents a uniform interface.

Comment: Could you show an example that actually represents what you are trying to achieve? This looks very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: So again, how does the code that only has a bunch of `CParent&` references in hand, would know to assign `char` to some of them but `int` to others? If you have that information somehow, then you could simply cast to `CChild1&` or `CChild2&` (at which point, it's unclear what `CParent` is for).

Comment: Note that `=` does not consider user-defined conversions for its left operand, and that you don’t need (and thus shouldn’t use) `reinterpret_cast` here.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> assign members of the children classes through a virtual function in the parent class without knowing the types of the members of the children class

That is not generally possible in C++. C++ is a statically typed language. As such, the type of every expression must be known at compile time. Templates follow this rule as well; they simply permit the generation of functions/classes/etc based on particular types. So with a template function that takes a type parameter `T`, there are an infinite number of possible functions that could be generated. The compiler only generates the ones which are statically used.

This is static polymorphism.

This template generation of functions is also why `virtual` template functions aren't allowed. By definition, there would have to be an infinite number of versions of them, and a derived class would have to implement each. And the `virtual` mechanism usually relies on the identity of a function, which doesn't really exist for a template.

`virtual` functions express dynamic/runtime polymorphism. These are based on prototypes defined in base classes, which are implemented in derived classes. But those prototypes are just *regular functions*. Functions which have a full function signature including their return type. A signature that must follow the rules of C++: the types are known at compile-time.

As such, the only way to implement what you're talking about is to package the value in a way that the compiler does not get to know what the type is, but the source and destination do. `std::any` is a decent tool for this.

Comment: *"template functions aren't allowed. By definition, there would have to be an infinite number of versions of them"* is this because they have to be known ahead of time, i.e. during compilation, way before the link time where some other module would try to use such class? and so if a compiler were to be required to be present at link (or even run) time, it *would* then be able to generate and compile any specific type of such function as might be needed, at an actual call site? (I understand this wouldn't be a (today's?) C++ then, just would appreciate feedback to see if I got this right).

Comment: @WillNess: "*so if a compiler were to be required to be present*" No, you would need to potentially recompile the *entire* application. Remember: most implementations of virtual functions use vtables, which are structs containing function pointers. A *specific number* of function pointers. Every time a new instantiation were produced, a new function pointer would have to magically appear. Which would have to change a vtable that is being used by objects. Even [P1609](https://wg21.link/P1609) ensures that JIT-C++ is careful to avoid things that change *existing* code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. looks like implementation issue? maybe vtables could be implemented differently, or the whole overriding mechanism...  yeah this would probably be even farther from C++ as it is. I thought it would *replace* (not *add*) one of the pointers with a specific version for this or that specific instantiation type. but it has been too long since I wrote C++ and my knowledge of these things is sketchy. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with that requires minimal change from your posted code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Base class to be able to hold pointers to derived class instances.
class CParent
{
   bool m_bExampleParentData = true;
   public:

      // Add this to make sure deleting object through base class pointers works
      // as well as dynamic_cast is supported.
      virtual ~CParent() {}
};

// Base class to allow inheritance of specific conversion operators.
template <typename T>
class TParent
{
   public:
      virtual operator T() = 0;
};

// By inheriting from TParent<char&>, this class must support conversion
// to char& to allow instantation of class objects.
class CChild1: public CParent, public TParent<char&>
{
    char m_chExampleChild1Data = 'c';

    operator char & ( ) override
    {
        return m_chExampleChild1Data;
    }
};

// By inheriting from TParent<int&>, this class must support conversion
// to int& to allow instantation of class objects.
class CChild2: public CParent, public TParent<int&>
{
    int m_iExampleChild2Data = 17;

    operator int & ( ) override
    {
        return m_iExampleChild2Data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< CParent * > vecAbstractPointers;

    CChild1 child1;
    vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( reinterpret_cast< CParent * >( &child1 ) );
    CChild2 child2;
    vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( reinterpret_cast< CParent * >( &child2 ) );

    // Rather ugly casts to allow assignment of 'b' and 8.
    static_cast<char&>(*(dynamic_cast<TParent<char&>*>(vecAbstractPointers[0]))) = 'b';
    static_cast<int&>(*(dynamic_cast<TParent<int&>*>(vecAbstractPointers[1]))) = 8;

    // Rather ugly casts to allow extraction of 'b' and 8.
    std::cout << static_cast<char&>(*(dynamic_cast<TParent<char&>*>(vecAbstractPointers[0]))) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<int&>(*(dynamic_cast<TParent<int&>*>(vecAbstractPointers[1]))) << std::endl;
}
```

**PS** Please don't use such code in real world applications. I am sure there is a better design for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CParent
{
  bool m_bExampleParentData = true;
public:
  virtual operator int&( ) { exit(-1); }
  virtual operator bool&( ) { exit(-1); }
};
template<class T>
class Child:public CParent
{
  T t;
public:
  operator T&() override { return t; }
};
using CChild1=Child<int>;
using CChild2=Child<bool>;
```

then:

```
std::vector< CParent * > vecAbstractPointers;

CChild1 child1;
vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( &child1 );
CChild2 child2;
vecAbstractPointers.emplace_back( &child2 );

*vecAbstractPointers[ 0 ] /*char( child1 )*/ = 'b';
*vecAbstractPointers[ 1 ] /*int( child2 )*/ = 8;
```

compiles.

This is a bad idea.